# JLabel with Icon aligned to left

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel

I have a JLabel with a Icon and text aligned to bottom, the icon is center to the text,
how do i have the Text and the icon aligned to left and the text below the icon.

My current code is as below

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fileName));
label.setText("This text is going to be varying size and can be bit long");

label.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Looks like you have the best combination :) See [Variations on a text and icon label](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Variationsonatextandiconlabel.htm) example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: I cheated]

If you mean someting like this, then I cheated.

Basically, I created two `JLabel`s on a `JPanel`.  Using a `GridBagLayout` I aligned the two labels onto of each other and anchored to the `WEST`

It would pretty easy to create a custom component for the purpose if you wanted to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

your just setting the Position of your text in your code..not the Icon it self

Try to separate the icon in the label then format it using set bounds or any formlayout